# How can a mean-field hubbard model describe itinerant ferromagnetism?

Tags: quantum-spin, many-body, ferromagnetism

I see some textbooks showing how Hubbard model with Mean field approximation can explain ferromagnetism of band electrons(stoner theory), but intuitively I can't understand why an *on-site* Hubbard repulsion term (rather than say Heisenberg term which correlate *neighboring* sites) can lead to a long-range ferromagnetic correlation. Although hubbard U seems to prefer non-zero spin at a certain site, whether one site's spin is up or down will not have any influence on another site's spin direction, so by what means are different sites correlated?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it can be understood by considering a strong Hubbard repulsion, and looking at the second order perturbation terms that come from the hopping (first order leads out of the state space where there's one electron per site, and the ground state will lie in that space for strong repulsion). These will then have the form of an effective spin-spin interaction.

Comment: (I am not sure, however, how to connect this analysis with the mean-field result).

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2259.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the large $U$ limit, if you treat the hopping as a perturbation, I think that you will always find an antiferromagnetic interaction in the effective $t$-$J$ model.

To see the effective ferromagnetic interaction, the other limit is more appropriate (large hopping, weak interactions). In this case, the electrons are completely delocalized to gain energy from the hopping term and the interaction can be approximated in the usual mean field sense by $U n_{i, \uparrow} n_{i, \downarrow} \approx U \langle n_\uparrow \rangle \langle n_\downarrow\rangle$. For repulsive $U>0$, one can check that an equal filling of up and down spins is energetically unfavorable for the interactions. Since unequal filling is better for interactions but worse for kinetic energy, one can calculate the critical interaction strength above which it is energetically favorable to have an unequal filling of spins, and therefore ferromagnetism. This is the Stoner instability.

To summarize: yes the interaction is on-site and naively it does not correlate nearest neighbor spins. The correlations between sites comes due to the kinetic energy term. But it is important to note that the $U/t \ll 1$ limit (Stoner ferromagnetism) is qualitatively different from the $U/t \gg 1$ limit ($t$-$J$ antiferromagnetism from second order perturbation theory).

Answer (score 0):

That is because apart from local Hubbard interaction there is a hopping term which induces interaction between different sites. Only both these terms lead to long range ferromagnetic correlation. For example, at large $U$ the model reduces to a $t-J$ model with Heisenberg interaction proportional to $t^2/U$ so without hopping there would be no ferromagnetism there.

Comment: Can I understand intuitively that ferromagnetic configuration is favored by kinetic energy lowering?  And what's the role played by Hubbard U here in generating ferromagnetism?